# Enviar um modelView como parametro para uma modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, post

Ao procurar por como renderizar uma `partialView` em uma modal *bootstrap*, encontrei este link: [Using Bootstrap Modal window as PartialView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231862/using-bootstrap-modal-window-as-partialview), só que eu preciso fazer uma requisição `POST` ao clicar no botão que abre a modal. Ou seja, preciso enviar o `modelView` atual da minha *main View* para a *partial view*.

Alguém poderia me dizer como adaptar o exemplo "GetGameListing" do link acima para alcançar meu objetivo?

EDIT 1: Adição de código.

Model:

```
public class SearchByCooperator
{
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public string m_Nome { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Cota")]
    public string m_Cota { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Cartão")]
    public string m_Cartao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Cidade")]

    public string m_Cidade{ get; set; }
    public string m_LojaAtendimento { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Acompanhantes")]
    public List<NomeIdCooperado> m_Acompanhantes { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data Visita")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime m_DataVisita { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GerarEtiquetas(SearchByCooperator v_model)
    {

    }
```

View:

```
<div class="span">
<button id='gerar'>Gerar</button>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-     labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 750px; margin-left: -375px;"     data-url='@Url.Action("GerarEtiquetas")'>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content" id="etiqueta_container">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
  $('#gerar').click(function () {
  var url = $('#myModal').data('url');
  var data = '@COOPA.Core.Common.JsonUtil.ToJson(Model)';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#etiqueta_container').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function (args) {
                    alert("erro");
            }

            });
        });
```

Comment: ja tentou em vez de utilizar o `$.get()` utilizar o `$.post()`?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei exatamente o que essa linha faz:

```
var data = '@COOPA.Core.Common.JsonUtil.ToJson(Model)';
```

Mas `data` precisa ter o seguinte para funcionar:

```
{
    'm_Nome': 'Um nome qualquer',
    'm_Cota': 'Cota',
    'm_Cartao': 'Número do cartão',
    'm_Cidade': 'Id ou nome da cidade',
    'm_LojaAtendimento': 'Id ou nome da loja de atendimento'
}
```

O `Controller` está ok.

O JavaScript, portanto, fica assim:

```js
$('#gerar').click(function () {
    var url = $('#myModal').data('url');
    var data = '@COOPA.Core.Common.JsonUtil.ToJson(Model)';

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#etiqueta_container').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (args) {
                alert("erro");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado Cigano, funcionou perfeitamente. Consigo receber o evento no controller, so tenho um problema ainda. O meu model chega nulo no controller. Procurei pela internet,  e não achei exemplos que enviam o OBEJTO completo, somente alguns dados hard coded. Isso é possível?

Comment: Serialize seu objeto na mão em `JSON`. Edite por favor a pergunta e coloque a declaração do seu Model pra eu atualizar a resposta pra você.

Comment: Fiz a adição do código. Acho que o problema esta no meu JS, onde eu tento serializar direto pelo metodo "return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);" o meu model. Pelo oque entendi, tem que ser no braço correto?

Comment: Sim, pra ser garantido o `binding` das propriedades do `Model`.